# Error compiling, "cannot find symbol" on method that does exist

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors

I get the following error when trying to compile a project in NetBeans 8.0:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        dim_names.add(TheDim.getShortName().toUpperCase());
                            ^
  symbol:   method getShortName()
  location: variable TheDim of type Dimension
```

So `TheDim`, in this case, is an object of the `ucar.nc2.Dimension` class, for those familiar with the netCDF libraries (I'm using v4.3 if it helps at all). The method `getShortName()` definitely exists when I browse through the library both in the IDE and looking through the [JavaDoc](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/netcdf-java/v4.3/javadoc/ucar/nc2/Dimension.html). Just to state the obvious, yes netcdfAll-4.3.jar is in my project's libraries. When I run the code through debug mode it works fine.

Not sure what is up with this but it's preventing me from building the project. Any possible solutions or workarounds?

Comment: Did you import the correct `Dimension`?  There is also [java.awt.Dimension](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html).

Comment: That would seem like that would be the cause but nope. For this particular class the imports are a few java utils (Lists) and stuff from the ucar.nc2 package. Also checked to see if there were conflicting class names but still nope, I don't have any class named just "Dimension" that would conflict whether in that package or the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the type `ucar.nc2.Dimension`, the error message would be

```
location: variable TheDim of type ucar.nc2.Dimension
```

You probably defined your own Dimension class, in the default package. Don't define any class in the default package, ever, and if you have a Dimension class in the same package as your class, use the fully qualified name: `ucar.nc2.Dimension`.

Also, variables in Java should start witha  lowercase letter. To a Java programmer, your code reads as "`getShortName()` is a static method of the class `TheDim`", jusyt because you don't respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: People sure get touchy about naming conventions. Sorry about the typo. But anyways, no, there is no conflicting class I've made called "Dimension".

Comment: Show us the whole code of the class (omitting the irrelevant methods) from the very first line to the end (by editing your question). As I said, I tested all javac versions from Java 6 to Java 8, and they all display the fully qualified name of the class which doesn't have the method called. So if your error message is exact, you do have a Dimension class in the default package (and your class is in the default package, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use it). Maybe you haven't written it yourself. Is your class in the default package? What happens if you move it in a package?

Comment: I think that would be unnecessary extra effort. Instead, since the issue you have is that it just says Dimension instead of the whole package location, I forced an error with the Variable class (also in ucar.nc2). `theVar.getShortName();` changed to `theVar.GetShortName();`. It showed the error in the same fashion (as just Variable). Perhaps it's because of the imports? At any rate it worked fine and doesn't throw a compile error for the original line.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong about it, but not providing the requested details won't help you get a correct answer. Do provide more details. And also specify which compiler you're using, while you're at it.

Comment: Anyway, I made a completely new and empty project with just the netcdf library and the lines necessary to pop up that error and you're right it compiled fine. So I'm not sure where the conflict is, but I'll check the other libraries included for the original project. I am at least 99.9% certain it's not a class I wrote.